# git tag between localhost and production?

Tags: git

I have two computers, a localhost and a production.  On bash of localhost, I type

```
git tag 0.1
git push projectname master
```

Then on production I type

```
git pull projectname master
git tag -l
```

How come when I type `git tag -l` on production, 0.1 does NOT show up?  How do I push the tag on localhost to production as well?  Or is that NOT how git tags are supposed to be used?

I want all programmers who have a pull of my latest version of code to know that it's the official 0.1 version.  I figure a tag will let everyone know...but that's only if they can receive the tag in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do `git push projectname master --tags` to push all the tags to the remote git.

Comment: Or `git push projectname tag 0.1` to push just the `0.1` tag. This is useful if you have made other local tags that you do not want to publish for one reason or another (e.g. tags marking some object of (possibly temporary) interest: buggy commits to investigate, bisection results, abandoned topic branches, etc.).